# .equal() not working as expected

Tags: java, android

```
btntxt=alphbtn[0].getText().toString();
cntr=cnt;
Log.i("Chr", "" + cnt + " " + crtchr);
for (int i = 0; i<strlnth ; i++)
{
    crtchr=(String.valueOf(curntnam.charAt(i)));
    if (strlnth > 8 && i==7)
    {
        i++;
    }
    if (btntxt.equals((crtchr)))
    {
        bt[i].setText(crtchr);
        cnt++;
    }
    Log.i("Chr", ""+crtchr);}
    Log.i("BUTTN", ""+btntxt);
}
```

In the code above I want to compare a string to button text which a-z on each button respectively. I use a button array to store all 26 buttons of alphabets. When `curntnam` contain a word of 8 characters it works correctly, but when the word's characters exceeds 8 the the app is crashed and Log inside and out the loop give message in logcat correctly. When i click on the error this show me error in

`if (btntxt.equals((crtchr))){`

So what do I need to do make it correct for more than 8 character word? Please help me my app is completed but this error stop me to finish.

Comment: show the log when app crashes

Comment: What are you trying to do. Show it by sample data. `strlnth>8&&i==7` is confusing.

Comment: use compareTo() or matches();

Answer (score 0):

`btntxt` must be null if this line giving you an error. Control  `btntxt` is null or log this variable for control.

Answer (score 0):

There was a mistake in my code where the for loop was recall after 8 so it crash the app. Now I have solved my problem.

Comment: I've removed the supplementary question from this answer, since people will not see it there. If you have a new question, please ask that separately, linking to this question if you believe it is relevant.